# How to get all differences between two tables using a query to Excel

Tags: sql, excel, database-connection, hp-uft

I am trying to execute a query to get all differences between two tables in a xlsx file.
All I get is an execution error by UFT.
My tables contain 1000 rows and 13 columns, they are in two separated sheets within the same excel file.

```
Const adCmdTable = 2
Const adLockBatchOptimistic = 4
Const adLockOptimistic = 3

dim ado, rs
set ado = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")

connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=myfile.xlsx;Extended Properties=" & chr(34) & "Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"& chr(34) 
ado.Open connString


QUERY = "SELECT [A$A1:M100].*, [B$A1:M100].* FROM [A$A1:M100] FULL JOIN [B$A1:M100] ON ([A$A1:M100].KEY= [V$A1:M100].KEY) WHERE [A$A1:M100].KEY IS NULL OR [V$A1:M100].KEY IS NULL"
set ors = ado.Execute(QUERY)
```

What is wrong?
Thank you

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Hi @Dave, i have a Generic Error (it's not specified) when it tries to open the connection. What is strange is that this error is random. Sometimes i get it, sometimes the query works (i changed it by the way, I tried a simple select). I don't know why I have this random Generic Error by UFT...